# Get selected item from the completion popup menu

Tags: vim

I'm trying to implement a smart omni completion for some PLSQL function/procedure arguments. Every such function may be overloaded so, at the very beginning, I provide all arguments, from all overloaded versions. For example, supposing we have this:

```
    procedure test(param1 varchar2, param2 varchar2);  <= overload 1
    procedure test(p1 integer, p2 integer);    <= overload 2
    procedure test(p1 date, p2 date, p3 date); <= overload 3
```

the list I provide when I type `exec test(|<=cursor here` is:

```
param1 [o1]
param2 [o1]
p1 [o2]
p2 [o2]
p1 [o3]
p2 [o3]
p3 [o3]
```

If the user chooses `"p1 [o2]"` from the completion popup menu I want to remember his selection and, for the next completion attempts, to provide the list filtered with just [o2] parameters or to sort it differently, so that to display the [o2] items first.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the item the user has selected and accepted from the completion popup menu. Is there a clean way to achieve it? It's kind of funny that I have the whole user case scenario in mind but I got stuck before I even start. Without knowing what the user has selected from the list it's hard to implement this kind of "self-learning/adaptive" code-completion systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent Vim patch 7.3.598 introduces the `CompleteDone` event, but you can also use the `CursorMovedI` event, which fires after a completion candidate is inserted.

The keyword before the cursor (`matchstr(strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1), '\k\+$')`) is the inserted completion then; save it in a variable and consider this on the next completion. (You probably need to save the cursor position (via `getpos()`), too, to avoid considering when a brand new, unrelated completion at another place occurs instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I didn't know about the new CompleteDone event. At the first glance it looks like the best option, except that it's very new and, as far as I could see, the interface is not completely defined yet. The CursorMovedI approach might work, but I still cannot figure out if the user selected "p1 [o2]" or "p1 [o3]". The trailing [o1], [o2] are provided as the "kind" property of the completion item dictionary.

Comment: I use the `CursorMovedI` myself. You're right, the "kind" property is lost; the completion menu isn't meant for such a thing. You'd have to implement your own completion query (with `:echo` and `input()`) for that.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I posted a suggestion to Bram, maybe the index number of the selected item could be provided as part of this new CompleteDone event: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/vim_dev/XDFDQ8rkBII

Comment: Yeah, saw that. I'd prefer that the entire match object (with .word, .abbr, .kind, etc.) would be provided; this saves the script from remembering the entire list of matches beyond the completion itself, and it prevents the problem where Vim drops duplicates, but you have them in your list.

Comment: Yes, it sounds lovely! Indeed, having the entire hash returned would be much better, also considering that the initial completion list may be further narrowed down with every new character typed with the popup window open. This might as well lead to confusion about the meaning of the returned index number. So, I agree: the entire record should be returned. Hope Bram will also agree!

Comment: @IngoKarkat I think this [patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_dev/v$3Acompleted_item/vim_dev/fhGAStSCAMg/q5BIr2EcH4YJ) does it exactly what you want (returning the entire match object). Unfortunately it hasn't been merged yet.

Answer (score 3):

As of Vim 8.0 and neovim 0.1.5 (at the least, I'm not sure when exactly this was added) there is now a `v:completed_item` variable that contains the match object (see the `complete-items` help page) associated with the last completion (specifically, the last `CompleteDone` event). This variable contains an empty dictionary if the completion failed or when you leave and re-enter insert mode.

However, in order to use this to determine whether a completion item was explicitly selected, you must set `completeopt+=noinsert`. Otherwise `v:completed_item` will always be set to the first item in the completion menu after it opens, even if you haven't selected it explicitly.